# Error de compilación al publicar web en visual studio 2017 community

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Estoy utilizando visual comunity 2017
y deseo publicar una web.
Ya limpié la solución, re-compilé pero sigue saliendo ese mensaje, me sale el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este mensaje sale en el txt

```
02/10/2018 06:42:50 a.m.
System.AggregateException: Se han producido uno o varios errores. ---> System.Exception: Error de compilación. Compruebe la ventana de salida para obtener más detalles.
   --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la excepción interna ---
   en System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   en System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   en Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Publish.PublishService.VsWebProjectPublish.<>c__DisplayClass41_0.<PublishAsync>b__2()
   en System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   en System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   en Microsoft.VisualStudio.ApplicationCapabilities.Publish.ViewModel.ProfileSelectorViewModel.<RunPublishTaskAsync>d__116.MoveNext()
---> (Nº de excepción interna 0) System.Exception: Error de compilación. Compruebe la ventana de salida para obtener más detalles.<---

===================
```

Comment: Mira la ventana de "output" o "salida" (supongo que será así en castellano) a ver si te da más detalles del error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buena la solución que me resulto fue solo ejecutar el visual studio como administrador y recién me permitió publicar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: @Kleith verifico en mi respuesta que no dice gracia, otro no puedo aceptar la respuesta porque tiene que pasar 21 horas para recien aceptar ya que no me permite. porque sino ya lo hubiera aceptado como respuesta

Comment: Perdón pero me equivoqué, lo que quería decir que esto no es una respuesta sino que un comentario. No debería estar acá.

Comment: @Kleith capas no hay otra forma de poder responder pero es una respuesta a mi problema. ya que ni es código ni comando . y creo que si dio solución debería ser una respuesta y no un comentario.

Answer (score 1):

Tuve el mismo error. Comprobé la ventana de salida de actividad de publicación, como dice el mensaje, y vi que había un error: una de mis vistas a las que hacía referencia el explorador de soluciones no existía en el sistema de archivos.

La eliminé y funcionó.

saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Ya veo que solucionaste,

- trata de elevar los privilegios de tu usuario para que sea administrador del equipo.
- O cambia de propietario la carpeta para que tu usuario sea el dueño.
- Pero en todo caso en una computadora de desarrollo es preferible que tu usuario sea administrador para que no tengas ese tipo de problemas.

Qué bueno que tú mismo encontraste la solución.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que asegurar que el usuario de la PC es un usuario tipo administrador, a mi me sucedió este problema cuando intente publicar un proyecto en una pc donde no tenía perfil de administrador.

Answer (score 0):

Tuve el mismo problema, e igual faltaba un archivo NO importante, lo borré del explorador de soluciones y listo, la publicación se hace sin problemas.